# Hiding labels on y axis in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to hide labels in line chart drawn using library [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). I googled but no luck. Could that be hidden?

Thanks

Comment: you can use the scaleShowLabels option - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options

Comment: `scaleShowLabels` does not exist in the document.

Answer (score 102):

To hide just the labels, in version 2.3.0 of Charts.js, you disable `ticks` like so:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: To also hide the tick marks themselves, add `gridLines: { tickMarkLength: 0 }` to the y axis definition (tested in version 2.9.4).

Answer (score 28):

For version 2, you can do this with the [Scales](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales) option in the global configuration.

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("log");
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: false
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: false
          }],
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'],
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            data: [10, 20, 30]
        }]
      }
    });
```

Comment: This completely removes the axes, not just the labels.

Comment: I <3 real life heroes :D

Answer (score 22):

For version 3.x

```
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      ticks: {
        display: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will hide the y labels.

Answer (score 13):

This will hide labels in Y-Axis: (but not X-Axis)

```
    scaleShowLabels: false,
```

Comment: @Raptor and how exactly have you proposed this.

Answer (score 10):

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: true,
              color: 'rgba(219,219,219,0.3)',
              zeroLineColor: 'rgba(219,219,219,0.3)',
              drawBorder: false, // <---
              lineWidth: 27,
              zeroLineWidth: 1                 
            },
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                display: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.display = false;
```

Comment: Some explanation would make your answer more helpful to the OP and those who follow.

Comment: This one hides the labels on both axes though.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it with overriding y-axis labels width

```
Chart.Scale.prototype.buildYLabels = function () {
  this.yLabelWidth = 0;
};
```

Comment: Nope, Just added this code in my custom js file, which is loaded after chart.js

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
 var statDat = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [
        {
            fillColor: "rgba(255, 152, 0, 0.30)",
            strokeColor: "#f26b5f",
            pointColor: "#f26b5f",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#00fff5",
            pointStrokeColor: "#f26b5f",
            data: [203, 156, 99, 251, 305, 247]
        }
    ]
};

var stats = document.getElementById('stats').getContext('2d');

var options = {
    scaleShowLabels: false 
};

new Chart(stats).Line(statDat, options);
```

Answer (score 3):

This should remove all text(legends and labels) and all gridlines:

```
const chartOptions = {
responsive: true,
plugins: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  // title: {
  //   display: true,
  //   text: "Chart",
  // },
},
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
      drawBorder: false,
    },
    ticks: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  y: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
      drawBorder: false,
    },
    ticks: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
},
```

};

Answer (score 2):

if you are using 3.3.2
Y axis will be hidden by this:

```
options: 
{
    scales: {
        yAxis: {
            display: false,
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with Chartjs v2.4.0

The idea is to set backDropColor to full transparent. 255,255,255 is white, but 0 sets it to transparent.

Then the userCallback returns always an emptry string.

The end result is hidden y-axis labels.

```
  ticks: {
    backdropColor : "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            display: false
        }
     }]
   }
 }
```