# Remove y and x axis lines and change axis font style in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to completley remove the lines from the y and x axis, not just the grid lines but the left and bottom lines. Additionally, how would I change the font style of the axis labels to a custom font?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding labels on y axis in Chart.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716464/hiding-labels-on-y-axis-in-chart-js)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to completley remove the lines from the y and x axis, not just
>   the grid lines but the left and bottom lines.

Just set the scale line color to transparent in the options, like so

```
    ...
    scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    ...
```

---

> Additionally, how would I change the font style of the axis labels to
>   a custom font?

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/34176161/360067, just set the font-face in your CSS and then set the scale font family, like so

**CSS**

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        src: /* path to your font files */
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

**Script**

```
    ...
    scaleFontFamily: "'FontAwesome'",
    ...
```