# How to hide the tick marks of the axis in react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plot, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to display the axisY without labels, but this is not work

````
  scales:{
    yAxes:[{
      scaleLabel:{
        display: false
      }
    }],
  },
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the below code works?

```
scales:{
yAxes:[{
  scaleLabel:{
    display: false
  },
  ticks: {
    display:false // it should work
  }
 }],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431433/795683)

options: {
scales: {
yAxes: [{
ticks: {
display: false
}
}]
}
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide label, use following

```
scales:{
    yAxes:[{
       ticks:{
       display: false
      }
    }]
}
```

Same goes for xAxes