# Hiding labels on y axis in Chart.js 3.5.0 not working properly

Tags: javascript, charts

This driving me nuts. I tried all of the stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716464/hiding-labels-on-y-axis-in-chart-js)  and looked to documentation https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html

but still not able to remove y-axis labels from bar charts.
Which part I could be missing ?
Here is the part of the code that defines
y axis stuff

```
<script>
             
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var chartOptions = {
                          
                            scales: {
                               
                                y: {
                                       display: true
                                    }
                               
                            
                            }
                        };

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'bar',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: {{ countrynames|safe }},
            datasets: [{
              
                label: 'Infected Counts',
                barThickness:'flex',
                backgroundColor:'#03a9fc', 
                backgroundColor : 'rgb(255,99,132)' ,
                borderColor : 'rgb(255,99,132)' ,
                data: {{ barPlotVals|safe }}
               
            }]
        },

        

        // Configuration options go here
        options: { indexAxis: 'y', chartOptions}
         
});
        
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a runnable [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces this issue?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule hey! sorry for my late response! I'm copy the some of the code from [here](https://github.com/sharmasw/DjangoDashboardCorona)! and edited the OP including the javascript part.